# How to set view column to the value of a table column only if that column exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run the following CREATE VIEW script which needs to have a column value either be blank ('') if the column doesn't exist in another table, or be that column's value if it does.

```
CREATE VIEW [DG].[PERIOD_FCY] AS 

DECLARE @FIY TINYINT

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PERIOD' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FIYNUM_0'
) SET @FIY = 1  ELSE SET @FIY = 0 

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @FIY = 1 THEN P.FIYNUM_0 ELSE '' END
    /*[...]*/
FROM [DCT].PERIOD P
```

Of course, the problem is that the case statement will always fail if the column doesn't exist (FIYNUM_0).

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: can't do this in the view. Stored proc - yea. You will need some dynamic SQL

Comment: Your columns always need to be well defined. Why would you create a view on a non-existent column? Perhaps you need dynamic SQL to create the view?

Comment: Another idea - create the view itself dynamically

Comment: I agree move the `if exists` check outside and dynamically build the create view statement.

Comment: Guess I'll have to brush up on my dynamic SQL! Thanks everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for doing this is, firstly you must create your own function for getting this field (FIYNUM_0) value by using PERIOD table primary key `id` field, and on this function, we will be controlling the existing column `FIYNUM_0`. If a column exists we return this field value from `PERIOD` table by using the input parameter as `id` field. Else we will return ''. For Example:

```
Create function GET_FIYNUM_0 
(
    @table_id integer
)  
returns 
    varchar(200)  
begin  
  declare 
  @pdata varchar(200)
  
    IF (exists(select tbl.object_id 
               from sys.columns col 
               inner join sys.tables tbl on tbl.object_id = col.object_id 
               where col.name = 'FIYNUM_0' and tbl.name = 'PERIOD')) 
    begin 
            SELECT @pdata = FIYNUM_0 from TEST_DB.dbo.PERIOD where id = @table_id
    end else 
    begin 
            SET @pdata = ''
    end
    
    RETURN @pdata
end
```

But after then, we can create our view very-very easily. Example:

```
CREATE VIEW PERIOD_FCY
AS
SELECT   
    dbo.GET_FIYNUM_0(PER.ID) as MYFIELD
from 
    TEST_DB.dbo.PERIOD PER
```

This `GET_FIYNUM_0(PER.ID)` will return `FIYNUM_0` field value when if this column exists, but in else will be return empty string.